# Full screen chrome without switching to new space

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to full screen chrome without having it switch to a new space? I use 2 monitors and full screen mode makes my second monitor unusable when chrome is in FS mode

<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

Is there away to avoid spaces when in this mode?

Comment: What is the version of Your OS X?

Comment: I am running 10.9.5

Comment: How exactly second screen is unusable? When I enter fs in *Chrome* I still can use second screen normally. Did You check "Desktop have separate spaces" in *Mission Control* preferences?

Comment: Its unusable in the sense that it becomes a giant gray block while chrome usurps 100% of the current monitors space, and no that option is not checked

Comment: So check it:) When it's not checked multi monitor mode works as in Lion for example. NOTE: after that You'll change spaces on monitors independently.

Comment: That worked - are you familiar with iTerms full screen mode? I'd like to be able to have apps full screened on the same monitor as chrome so i can cmd+tab and switch fs apps on same screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17345/discussion-between-mateusz-szlosek-and-lfender6445).